# New Custom keyboards not working in UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine, custom-keyboard

Unable to get Input using Custom Keyboards in an Unity App , both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

```
private var keyboard : TouchScreenKeyboard;
    var text : String = "";

    function Start() {
        keyboard = TouchScreenKeyboard.Open(text, TouchScreenKeyboardType.Default);
    }
    function Update() {
        if (keyboard != null && keyboard.done)
        {
            text = keyboard.text;
            print ("User input is: " + text);
        }
    }
```

Did you try this?